# Printing decimal numbers get rounded up in chicken-scheme

Tags: scheme, chicken-scheme

I have a scheme procedure that returns `0.24999999999999992` as a result. However, when I tried to `print` this result with chicken-scheme on my machine, it gets rounded to `0.25`. How can I prevent rounding?

I tried running the same procedure on repl.it, and the `print` command here outputs the result without rounding.

If it helps, the code below:

```
(define (sum term a next b)
  (if
    (> a b)
    0
    (+ (term a) (sum term (next a) next b))
  )
)

(define (integral-simpson f a b n)
  (define h (/ (- b a) n))
  (define (inc x) (+ x 1))
  (define (term x)
    (cond
      ((or (= x 0) (= x n)) (f (+ a (* x h))))
      ((even? x) (* 2 (f (+ a (* x h)))))
      ((odd? x) (* 4 (f (+ a (* x h)))))
    )
  )

  (* (/ h 3)
    (sum
      term
      a
      inc
      n
    )
  )
)

(define (cube x)
  (* x x x)
)

(print (integral-simpson cube 0 1 100))
```

Comment: How about not printing it? `integral-simpson` is already returning the value you want.

Comment: Prints `1/4` for me with chicken 5.2...

Comment: All of the operations used in the posted code return exact results per the Standard, so `integral-simpson` should return an exact result when the inputs are exact numbers. When I test `(integral-simpson cube 0 1 100)` in Chez Scheme, I get `1/4`. When I test `(integral-simpson cube 0 1.0 100)` I get `0.24999999999999992`.

Comment: @ÓscarLópez I want to print it to verify the result.

Comment: @exnihilo I tried with `(integral-simpson cube 0 1.0 100)` (note with 1.0 instead of 1) but that did not seem to work either on chicken-scheme. Answer from @sjamaan works

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing the [print precision](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/5/Module%20(chicken%20flonum)#flonum-limits): `(flonum-print-precision 17)`